# C++ deltatime using clock() is 0

Tags: c++

I am calculating the deltatime for my video game, so the gamespeed will not go insanely fast when someones PC is fast. I use the clock() function from the ctime library to measure the time. The problem is, that my fps is so high, that the deltatime is 0. So my gamespeed is also screwed up.

This is how I calculate the delta time:

```
///DELTATIME AND FPS COUNTING
deltaTime = clock() - oldTime;
double fps = (1 / deltaTime) * 1000;
oldTime = clock();
```

The variable types of deltaTime and oldTime are float.
I need to actually have the clock() function more accurate, so it is not 0(in milliseconds I believe).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `deltaTime`?

Comment: Actually, you probably don't want to use `clock()` anyway - it gives you the amount of CPU time that elapsed, not the amount of real time. In other words, if your CPU is used by other applications, not just your game, you'll get "slower" gameplay.

Comment: Do you understand what the `clock` function does? It doesn't measure wall time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It does [on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) (unfortunately).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, they even note that `[...] this is not strictly conformant with ISO C99, which specifies net CPU time as the return value.`. I guess they found out during compatibility testing that few applications use the correct function to get accurate walltime, which would break a lot of applications when transitioning to a pre-emptively multitasked environment (not to mention multi-threading). Still, it means that this use of `clock` isn't portable.

Comment: @interjay read my question...

Comment: What OS are you on? In Linux, there is a new scheduler that makes Linux closer to hard real-time, the SCHED_DEADLINE scheduler.

Comment: @ErikAlapää I am using Windows

Comment: I guess then you are out of luck ;) There are variants of Windows for embedded games and other embedded use, but I leave info about those to people who have worked embedded Windows more extensively than I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the literal `1` and the variable `deltaTime` (if a `clock_t`) are *integers*. Integer division will truncate the result, so `1 / anything_larger_than_1` will always be zero.

You need to use floating-point division instead:

```
1.0 / deltaTime
```

<sub>Note the use of the `double` literal `1.0`.</sub>

Comment: I don't think you understand my question, the problem is that the deltaTime is zero, because the application runs really fast.

Comment: @user5649862 Then you need to use a higher resolution timer. Both Windows and POSIX (e.g. Linux and OSX) have them. And if you have C++11 then there's of course the [chrono library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` instead. This guarantees a sleep time of at least the specified interval for the current thread, with minimal CPU usage.

Your specific problem is due to `1 / deltaTime` being computed in integer division. But even if you fix that, your timing method is unreliable due to other things running on the machine.

Comment: The OP's code is not for sleeping, it's for calculating the game speed.

Comment: It's difficult to calculate the game speed. I'm suggesting that this aspect is redesigned to use sleep.